# Does adding a vector to an independent list result in another independent list?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assuming that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is linearly independent in a vector space $V$, where $\dim V = \infty$. If you append $w\in V$, $w\neq 0$ to this list, is the resulting list linearly independent?

The question comes from trying a method other than what my book used to show that the list of polynomials $1,\dots,x^n\in\mathcal{P}(F)$ is linearly independent (I wanted to try induction instead of what he used in the example).

Comment: You cannot append a $w\in V$ to the list. It might be a linear combination of the $v_i$, e.g., $w=v_n$.

Comment: Not if $w \in \text{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$. If $w \not \in \text{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ then yes, you have a larger list of linearly independent vectors.